# Regex working in regex tester but fails when implemented in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that works fine on regex tester. Refer the below link:

https://regex101.com/r/4ogObc/4

But when I try to use it in python jupyter notebook, it does not match anything. This probably is because the tester has pcre(PHP) flavor.

Would be great if someone could help me fix this.

Comment: I recommend you first read  **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and then edit your question accordingly to attract more people to your question.

Comment: on the left side of the regex101 application is a selector box to which application the regex-flavor is.  if you select python, you'll see the errors.  Unfortunately php regex is not the same as python regex.

Comment: then why you try that? there is also option available for python

Comment: Because I dont know how to write the same thing to make it compatible with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[:punct:]]` is a method in php, other programming languages do not support it. It's the reason that your regex doesn't work.

The following regex can work on python or Javascript:

```
([a-zA-Z\.\(\)\:\-\?\*\&\^\%\$\#\@\!\`\~\/\\\'\"\;\,\.\<\>]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z\.\(\)\:\-\?\*\&\^\%\$\#\@\!\`\~\/\\\'\"\;\,\.\<\>]+)*)(\s+[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})
```

[Python regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Hg0.png)

But this regex is too long that I don't like it(Some too long regex will get time out)，therefore, as you see, this regex takes about 581ms, and your regex takes about 423ms. Now your test string is not too long, when you match a greater webpages(a web crawl), it can take some time.